# help with symbolic linking

Tags: symlink

hello im trying to make a user share folder
`/mnt/user/data` and link it do `/zfs/data`.

I'm trying to make both `/data` be the same folder so `/mnt/user/data/subfolder` will point to `/zfs/data/subfolder`.

I did `ln -s zfs/data /mnt/user` but it gives OS errors having `user/data` a linked folder.
I also tried linking the subfolders directly to `/user/data` and sense sub folders are not a dataset some things could not access subfolders when pointing to `/user/data`.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work besides making datasets for the subfolders?

Comment: you need to explain your pool and dataset and directory structure in more detail because `ln -s /zfs/data/ /mnt/user/` should work - it will make a symlink called `data` in `/mnt/user/` that points to `/zfs/data/`.  Any user (with the required permission or group membership) will be able to access the files and sub-directories in it from either /zfs/data/ or /mnt/user/data/ or both/either at their choice.

Comment: We don't understand what "OS errors" might mean.  Please post your full command with the output.

Comment: You also need to provide details about what is going wrong - what **exact** error message(s) (if any) did you see.  Vague reminiscences about some non-specific error message aren't at all useful.   And you need to be consistent in what you're saying.  You've said `/zfs/data` (with and without a leading `/`), just plain `/data`, and both `/mnt/user/data` and `/user/data` - which of these is actually correct?  Are you just typing in the wrong paths on your command line?

Comment: hello yes that works but the os doesnt want a folder created in /user that way.
error: share_luks_status, 5995: Operation not supported (95): getxattr: /mnt/user/data
is the error i get in logs doing it that way. this is on unraid.

Comment: i have added the link multiple ways /zfs/data and zfs/data/ but both results were the same. as far as that i was just simplify the path as to not include all every time. the full paths to the datas are /zfs/data on the zpool and /mnt/user/data on the array pool of unraid.

Comment: the problem is only /zfs/data is a dataset and not the sub folders. so if i add the subfolders to /mnt/user/data/subfolder apps see /data as blank. but if i point them to the subfolder instead its fine. making dataset subfolders is an option but would take a very long time transferring data to them. im not sure if i can get around the unraid linking directly to /mnt/user error or not

Comment: no, that's not the problem.  a symlink works as long as whatever it points to exists - doesn't matter if it's to a file or a directory or a top-level dataset or a child dataset.   When you ran `ln -s`, did you use `/zfs/data` as the target, or `/zfs/data/` (with a trailing /).  They're mostly the same, but there are some minor, subtle differences in how they work (i've mostly seen those diffs in shell, esp. with tab-completion but it's possible that whatever you're running also treats them differently).  Having a trailing / on the target for a symlink to a dir generally works best, I've found.

Comment: also, is `zfs` actually the name of your zfs pool?  and `zfs/data` is a dataset (made with `zfs create`, not just a subdir of the pool's top-level dataset).   And I just noticed the error message is about luks.....what's that got to do with symlinks? or zfs datasets?   Is your dataset a zvol that you've encrypted with LUKS and mounted?   BTW, are you aware that ZFS has its own encryption capability for datasets?

Comment: `ln -s zfs/data /mnt/user` and `ln -s /zfs/data /mnt/user` are not equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.